# How to get metric in correct units in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I use Grafana 8.5 in Windows Server 2019.
My system collects data about the operation of the device. The metrics are:

- the number of correctly processed packets
- number of incorrectly processed packets
- number of total packets processed
- number of correlations
- signal level
  For these metrics I use Gauge.
  In Grafana I use "time series" graph for visualization.

Next, for example, I use this expression for “All_packets” in Grafana:

```
rate(Device_counter{Metric_name="All_packets"}[1m] )
```

After that I get the data, but the values ​​on the graph do not match the input data. For example, if there are 500 packages in “All_packets”, then on the graph I get much less (for example, 5.65). 
Perhaps I need to use another function instead of rate()?